# how to block packetflood originating from certain network but different IPs

Tags: firewall, tcp, ddos

i am receiving massive amount of bogus connections from 
ttnet.net.tr and their DSL subscribers.
what is the best way to deal with it? contact their abuse email?

i cannot block the IPs. there are way too many different ones. how is it possible to do such an attack?

Comment: Can you block their entire netblock?

Answer (score 1):

if found the solution for TTNET blocks the whole ISP

```
IPTABLES -A INPUT -s 62.248.0.0/17 -j DROP
```

and then just repeat that for these

```
 78.111.96.0/20
    78.111.96.0/22
    78.111.100.0/22
    78.111.104.0/21
    78.111.104.0/24
    78.111.105.0/24
    78.111.106.0/24
    78.111.107.0/24
    78.160.0.0/17
    78.160.128.0/17
    78.161.0.0/17
    78.161.128.0/17
    78.162.0.0/17
    78.162.128.0/17
    78.163.0.0/17
    78.163.128.0/17
    78.164.0.0/17
    78.164.128.0/17
    78.165.0.0/17
    78.165.128.0/17
    78.166.0.0/17
    78.166.128.0/17
    78.167.0.0/17
    78.167.128.0/17
    78.168.0.0/17
    78.168.128.0/17
    78.169.0.0/17
    78.169.128.0/17
    78.170.0.0/17
    78.170.128.0/17
    78.171.0.0/17
    78.171.128.0/17
    78.172.0.0/17
    78.172.128.0/17
    78.173.0.0/17
    78.173.128.0/17
    78.174.0.0/17
    78.174.128.0/17
    78.175.0.0/17
    78.175.128.0/17
    78.176.0.0/17
    78.176.128.0/17
    78.177.0.0/17
    78.177.128.0/17
    78.178.0.0/17
    78.178.128.0/17
    78.179.0.0/17
    78.179.128.0/17
    78.180.0.0/17
    78.180.128.0/17
    78.181.0.0/17
    78.181.128.0/17
    78.182.0.0/17
    78.182.128.0/17
    78.183.0.0/17
    78.183.128.0/17
    78.184.0.0/17
    78.184.128.0/17
    78.185.0.0/17
    78.185.128.0/17
    78.186.0.0/17
    78.186.128.0/17
    78.187.0.0/17
    78.187.128.0/17
    78.188.0.0/17
    78.188.128.0/17
    78.189.0.0/17
    78.189.128.0/17
    78.190.0.0/17
    78.190.128.0/17
    78.191.0.0/17
    78.191.128.0/17
    80.93.208.0/20
    80.93.208.0/24
    80.93.209.0/24
    80.93.210.0/24
    80.93.211.0/24
    80.93.212.0/24
    80.93.213.0/24
    80.93.214.0/24
    80.93.215.0/24
    80.93.216.0/24
    80.93.217.0/24
    80.93.218.0/24
    80.93.219.0/24
    80.93.220.0/24
    80.93.221.0/24
    80.93.222.0/24
    80.93.223.0/24
    81.212.0.0/14
    81.212.0.0/17
    81.212.128.0/17
    81.212.141.0/24
    81.213.0.0/17
    81.213.47.0/24
    81.213.128.0/17
    81.214.0.0/17
    81.214.12.0/24
    81.214.128.0/17
    81.215.0.0/17
    81.215.128.0/17
    85.96.0.0/12
    85.96.0.0/17
    85.96.128.0/17
    85.97.0.0/17
    85.97.128.0/17
    85.98.0.0/17
    85.98.128.0/17
    85.99.0.0/17
    85.99.128.0/17
    85.100.0.0/17
    85.100.128.0/17
    85.101.0.0/17
    85.101.128.0/17
    85.102.0.0/17
    85.102.128.0/17
    85.103.0.0/17
    85.103.128.0/17
    85.104.0.0/17
    85.104.128.0/17
    85.105.0.0/17
    85.105.128.0/17
    85.106.0.0/17
    85.106.128.0/17
    85.107.0.0/17
    85.107.128.0/17
    85.108.0.0/16
    85.108.0.0/17
    85.108.128.0/17
    85.109.0.0/17
    85.109.128.0/17
    85.110.0.0/17
    85.110.128.0/17
    85.111.0.0/17
    85.111.0.0/24
    85.111.1.0/24
    85.111.2.0/24
    85.111.3.0/24
    85.111.5.0/24
    85.111.6.0/24
    85.111.7.0/24
    85.111.8.0/24
    85.111.9.0/24
    85.111.10.0/24
    85.111.11.0/24
    85.111.12.0/24
    85.111.128.0/17
    88.224.0.0/11
    88.224.0.0/17
    88.224.128.0/17
    88.225.0.0/17
    88.225.128.0/17
    88.226.0.0/17
    88.226.128.0/17
    88.227.0.0/17
    88.227.128.0/17
    88.228.0.0/17
    88.228.128.0/17
    88.229.0.0/17
    88.229.128.0/17
    88.230.0.0/17
    88.230.128.0/17
    88.231.0.0/17
    88.231.128.0/17
    88.232.0.0/17
    88.232.128.0/17
    88.233.0.0/17
    88.233.128.0/17
    88.234.0.0/17
    88.234.128.0/17
    88.235.0.0/17
    88.235.128.0/17
    88.236.0.0/17
    88.236.128.0/17
    88.237.0.0/17
    88.237.128.0/17
    88.238.0.0/17
    88.238.128.0/17
    88.239.0.0/17
    88.239.128.0/17
    88.240.0.0/17
    88.240.128.0/17
    88.241.0.0/17
    88.241.128.0/17
    88.242.0.0/17
    88.242.128.0/17
    88.243.0.0/17
    88.243.128.0/17
    88.244.0.0/17
    88.244.128.0/17
    88.245.0.0/17
    88.245.128.0/17
    88.246.0.0/17
    88.246.128.0/17
    88.247.0.0/17
    88.247.128.0/17
    88.248.0.0/17
    88.248.128.0/17
    88.249.0.0/17
    88.249.128.0/17
    88.249.188.0/22
    88.250.0.0/17
    88.250.128.0/17
    88.251.0.0/17
    88.251.128.0/17
    88.252.0.0/17
    88.252.128.0/17
    88.253.0.0/17
    88.253.128.0/17
    88.254.0.0/17
    88.254.128.0/17
    88.255.0.0/17
    88.255.32.0/24
    88.255.45.0/24
    88.255.46.0/24
    88.255.57.0/24
    88.255.61.0/24
    88.255.70.0/24
    88.255.83.0/24
    88.255.91.0/24
    88.255.92.0/24
    88.255.95.0/24
    88.255.107.0/24
    88.255.128.0/17
    88.255.235.0/24
    93.155.102.0/24
    95.0.0.0/16
    95.0.0.0/17
    95.0.128.0/17
    95.1.0.0/17
    95.1.128.0/17
    95.2.0.0/17
    95.2.128.0/17
    95.3.0.0/17
    95.3.128.0/17
    95.4.0.0/17
    95.4.128.0/17
    95.5.0.0/17
    95.5.128.0/17
    95.6.0.0/17
    95.6.128.0/17
    95.7.0.0/17
    95.7.128.0/17
    95.8.0.0/17
    95.8.128.0/17
    95.9.0.0/17
    95.9.128.0/17
    95.10.0.0/17
    95.10.128.0/17
    95.11.0.0/17
    95.11.128.0/17
    95.12.0.0/17
    95.12.128.0/17
    95.13.0.0/17
    95.13.128.0/17
    95.14.0.0/17
    95.14.128.0/17
    95.15.0.0/17
    95.15.128.0/17
    192.175.128.0/23
    193.34.132.0/23
    193.109.134.0/23
    193.140.56.0/21
    193.189.142.0/24
    193.201.128.0/22
    193.201.128.0/24
    193.201.129.0/24
    193.201.130.0/24
    193.201.131.0/24
    193.218.200.0/24
    194.9.174.0/24
    194.54.32.0/19
    194.54.32.0/20
    194.54.56.0/22
    195.137.222.0/24
    195.137.223.0/24
    195.149.85.0/24
    195.174.0.0/15
    195.174.0.0/17
    195.174.128.0/17
    195.174.128.0/18
    195.174.192.0/18
    195.175.0.0/17
    195.175.128.0/17
    195.175.128.0/18
    195.175.192.0/18
    195.182.42.0/24
    195.244.32.0/19
    195.244.32.0/21
    195.244.40.0/21
    195.244.48.0/20
    195.245.227.0/24
    212.108.128.0/19
    212.156.0.0/16
    212.156.0.0/17
    212.156.128.0/17
    212.156.154.0/24
    212.174.0.0/15
    212.174.0.0/17
    212.174.54.0/24
    212.174.55.0/24
    212.174.128.0/17
    212.174.167.0/24
    212.174.217.0/24
    212.174.230.0/24
    212.175.0.0/17
    212.175.7.0/24
    212.175.64.0/21
    212.175.84.0/24
    212.175.111.0/24
    212.175.128.0/17
    212.175.234.0/24
    213.139.239.0/24
    213.238.151.0/24
    213.238.157.0/24
    217.195.192.0/20
    217.195.192.0/21
    217.195.193.0/24
    217.195.197.0/24
    217.195.200.0/24
    217.195.201.0/24
    217.195.202.0/24
    217.195.203.0/24
    217.195.204.0/24
    217.195.205.0/24
    217.195.206.0/24
    217.195.207.0/24
```

Comment: There're too many duplicate/unneeded lines. Use a CIDR calculator to shorten the number of lines by an order magnitude. For example, 78.111.96.0/18, 80.93.208.0/20 already cover subsequent lines. 78.160.* could be handled by 78.160.0.0/12 etc.